# avoid warning when doing class extention

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, categories

I want to do the following :

```
@interface UINavigationController ()

-(void)removeFromNavigationStack:(Class)aClass;

@end
```

and in .m file

```
@implementation UINavigationController

-(void)removeFromNavigationStack:(Class)aClass {

}
```

but in the .m file there are a lot of warning like "Method definition for 'initWithRootViewController:' not found"

how can I avoid this ? I've tried including  but still have the warnings

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're dealing with `UINavigationController`, a UIKit class, you probably want to go with a category, instead. Extensions need to be defined within the main `@implementation` block of the class's implementation, and you don't have access to that for `UINavigationController`

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1):

> Class extensions are like anonymous categories, except that the methods they declare must be implemented in the main @implementation block for the corresponding class. Using the Clang/LLVM 2.0 compiler, you can also declare properties and instance variables in a class extension.

Comment: Note that, in general, adding functionality to existing classes via a category is discouraged.   It interleaves your code with 'kit code in ways that will be difficult to maintain over time.  If you are going to add a method via a category, make sure you prefix it to avoid collisions;  i.e. `tahirRemoveFromNavigationStack:`.   This also makes it easy to spot added functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Add your class extension in your .m file.

Comment: so how will I include the extention in other .m files ? as there will be no .h

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Maybe you need a category and not a class extension.

Comment: "Add your class extension in your .m file." It is not *his* `.m` file where the intended extensions belong :)

Comment: Oops, i didn't saw the class name ^^. So in this case you need a category and not a class extension !!!

Comment: Won't help; needs a category.